# Testing OnDestroy component observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx

I have a component, which calls on some observables and listens to them, and cleans the subscriptions (advances and closes them) on destroy, but I can't seem to get the test working properly. Am I running the test wrong? The component does clean up its observables.

Component

```
export class DevicesComponent implements OnDestroy {
   public completer$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   this.deviceFacade.dataLoaded$.pipe(takeUntil(this.completer$)).subscribe({
            next: (loading: boolean) => {
                if (!loading) {
                    this.spinner.show();
                } else {
                    this.spinner.hide();
                }
            },
            error: (err: string | null) => console.log(err),
        });

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.completer$.next();
        this.completer$.complete();
    }
}
```

Test

```
    it('should call method and unsubscribe on destroy', () => {
        const destroy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnDestroy');
        const next = spyOn(component.completer$, 'next');
        const complete = spyOn(component.completer$, 'complete');

        component.ngOnDestroy();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(destroy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(complete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wanting to test the lifecycle hook in angular, and we can do that!

The `fixture.destroy()` method is what you'll want to call, but first let's talk about your use of `spyOn`.

When you call `spyOn(someObj, 'someProperty')` it spys on it and OVERWRITES the function to do nothing. Instead, when you need to spy on a function and still have the function run as normal, you should use `spyOn(someObj, 'someProperty).and.callThrough()`. As you have it written the ngOnDestroy method won't do anything.

As for your test, what you really want to know is that your subscriptions have been closed. The best approach is to make sure that your dependencies are interacted with as you expect.

```
it('should call method and unsubscribe on destroy', () => {
  // try to avoid spying on your component - it is what you're testing!
  //const destroy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnDestroy');
  //const next = spyOn(component.completer$, 'next');
  //const complete = spyOn(component.completer$, 'complete');
  
  // you should have a deviceFacade service that is set to a subject or behaviorSubject in the beforeEach
  // fakeDeviceFacade.dataLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  // it won't work if you set fakeDeviceFacade.dataLoaded$ = of(something) 
  expect(fakeDeviceFacade.dataLoaded$.observers.length).toBe(1);
  fixture.destroy();
  expect(fakeDeviceFacade.dataLoaded$.observers.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`spyOn` doesn't invoke the actual implementation by default.
You can enable it with `and.callThrough()`

```
    it('should call method and unsubscribe on destroy', () => {
        const destroy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnDestroy').and.callThrough();
        const next = spyOn(component.completer$, 'next');
        const complete = spyOn(component.completer$, 'complete');

        component.ngOnDestroy();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(destroy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(complete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/jasmine-spyon.html